# How to use joins on Pro*C 10g?

Tags: oracle10g, inner-join, oracle-pro-c

While using inner join on Pro*C I am getting the below error:

```
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "inner" when expecting one of the following:
```

I've just used a simple inner join. When I searched for solution, I was told that 10g doesn't support these kind of syntax and I should use dynamic SQL instead. Is that true? How to achieve inner join using dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pro*C 10g version doesn't allow inner/outer joins. If you want to have these, you will have to upgrade your Pro*C compiler.
If you use, 11g you can use the solution suggested here: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=665519

Comment: you need 11g and the option "common_parser=yes", but other undesired things may happen (depending on other required settings)

Answer (score 0):

Use the old syntax.

Instead of: `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.PK = TABLE2.FK`

Use this: `SELECT * FROM TABLE1, TABLE2 WHERE TABLE1.PK = TABLE2.FK`

For OUTER JOINS just use the (+) sign on the side you want to be nullable:

Instead of: `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.PK = TABLE2.FK`

Use this: `SELECT * FROM TABLE1, TABLE2 WHERE TABLE1.PK = TABLE2.FK (+)`